# Yup and Formik - how to set variables for different conditions on password field

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

I have been searching through other posts and finding issues similar to but not quite what I am looking for.

I need to know simultaneously if the different conditions are met for a password to highlight the visual below.

What I'm seeing coming back right now is just the error message for the first condition that is not met.

The validation schema

```js
validationSchema: Yup.object({
            password: Yup.string()
                .required('Required')
                .min(8, 'Must be 8 characters or more')
                .matches(/[A-Z]+/, 'One uppercase character')
                .matches(/[@$!%*#?&]+/, 'One special character')
                .matches(/\d+/, 'One number'),
        }),
```

Here is the ui I want to be able to update just to help in case I'm not explaining well enough
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to create states for each condition like

```
const [isRequired, setRequired] = useState(false);
const [isMinLength, setMinLength] = useState(false);
const [isUppercase, setUppercase] = useState(false);
const [isSpecial, setSpecial] = useState(false);
//other validation states like isNumber...
```

You can use yup `.when` to check if password value satisfy your conditions or not.

```
validationSchema: Yup.object({
password: yup.string().when('password', (password, field) => {
            if (password == null) {
                setRequired(false)
                return field.required()
            } else {
                setRequired(true)
            }
        }).when('password', (password, field) => {
            if (password?.length <= 8) {
                setMinLength(false)
                return field.min(8, 'Must be 8 characters or more')
            } else {
               setMinLength(true)   //mark min length check as green
            }
        }).when('password', (password, field) => {
            if (!(/[A-Z]+/.test(password))) {
                setUppercase(false)
                return field.matches(/[A-Z]+/, 'One uppercase character')
            } else {
                setUppercase(true) //mark uppercase check as green
            }
        }).when('password', (password, field) => {
            if (!(/[@$!%*#?&]+/.test(password))) {
                setSpecial(false)
                return field.matches(/[@$!%*#?&]+/, 'One special character')
            } else {
                setSpecial(true)  //mark special character check as green
            }
        }),
}, ["password", "password"]),  //yup cyclic dependency
```

Similarly, like above you can create states and use `.when` for other validations as well. Based on those states you can change state of checkboxes or whatever the GUI you are using.

Comment: Thanks! Think this is getting my very close. TS is not liking the dependency array though... `Expected 0-1 arguments, but got 2.ts(2554)`

Comment: according to [this](https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/79) try `[["password", "password"]]`.

Comment: or try [yup.object().shape(...](https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/176#issuecomment-404047635)